# Autocomplete variable names in CodeMirror 6

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, editor, codemirror, code-completion

I've built a language support extension for CodeMirror 6 (Backus-Naur Form). It works just fine for syntax highlighting.

However, I'd like for CodeMirror to auto-complete the names of the rules the user has already defined.

I read the docs, but they only seem to explain how to autocomplete a fixed set of suggestions.

The API reference is also somewhat lacking in terms of its documentation on autocomplete-related classes/methods.

Does anyone know how to implement this?